# Processing.js - Continue interacting when mouse is out of canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing

I have a canvas on my header and when the user mouse over the canvas he / she can interact with the canvas. When the mouse is out the canvas the interaction stops. Is it possible to keep the interaction outside the canvas when the mouse moves in the whole document, while the user navigate the site.

I am using the processing.js and I don't know to write processing(I didn't write the code I am providing).I search a lot and try a bit myself with `mouseOut()` with no luck.

The code :

```
int factor = 2;
int bufferY = 20;
int bufferX = 10;

void setup()
{
  size(700, 200);
  strokeCap(SQUARE);
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  ArrayList<Linus> linus = new ArrayList<Linus>();

  for (int x=0; x<coordsArray.length; x++)
  {
    Linus l = new Linus(coordsArray[x][0]*factor+bufferX, coordsArray[x][1]*factor+bufferY, coordsArray[x][2]*factor+bufferX, coordsArray[x][3]*factor+bufferY);
    linus.add(l);
  }

  for (int x=0; x<coordsArray.length; x++)
  {
    linus.get(x).draw();
  }
}

class Linus
{
  float sX, sY, eX, eY;

  Linus(float _sX, float _sY, float _eX, float _eY) 
  {
    sX = _sX;
    sY = _sY;
    eX = _eX;
    eY = _eY;
  }

  void draw()
  {
    float weight = 1;
    weight = map(mouseX, 0, width, 1, 40);
    strokeWeight(weight);
    line(sX+weight/2, sY, eX+weight/2, eY);
  }
}
float[][] coordsArray =
{
{40 ,0 ,0 ,80},
{43 ,6 ,6 ,80},
{46 ,12 ,42 ,20},
{30 ,44 ,24 ,56 },
{49 ,18 ,45 ,26},
{36 ,44 ,30 ,56 },
{52 ,24 ,48 ,32},
{42 ,44 ,36 ,56 },
{55 ,30 ,51 ,38},
{48 ,44 ,42 ,56 },
{58 ,36 ,48 ,56},
{61 ,42 ,42 ,80},

{88 ,0 ,48 ,80},
{94 ,0 ,54 ,80},
{100 ,0 ,95 ,10},
{78 ,44 ,72 ,56 },
{106 ,0 ,101 ,10},
{84 ,44 ,78 ,56 },
{110 ,4 ,105 ,14},
{90 ,44 ,84 ,56 },
{113 ,10 ,90 ,56},
{116 ,16 ,102 ,44},
{98 ,52 ,93 ,62},
{119 ,22 ,112 ,36},
{102 ,56 ,96 ,68},
{136 ,0 ,133 ,6},
{105 ,62 ,99 ,74},
{142 ,0 ,137 ,10},
{108 ,68 ,102 ,80},
{148 ,0 ,143 ,10},
{111 ,74 ,108 ,80},
{154 ,0 ,149 ,10},
{160 ,0 ,120 ,80},
{166 ,0 ,126 ,80},
{172 ,0 ,167 ,10},
{178 ,0 ,173 ,10},
{184 ,0 ,179 ,10},
{188 ,4 ,185 ,10},
{194 ,4 ,159 ,74},
{202 ,0 ,162 ,80},
{208 ,0 ,203 ,10},
{186 ,44 ,180 ,56},
{173 ,70 ,168 ,80 },
{214 ,0 ,209 ,10},
{192 ,44 ,186 ,56},
{179 ,70 ,174 ,80 },
{220 ,0 ,215 ,10},
{198 ,44 ,192 ,56},
{185 ,70 ,180 ,80 },
{224 ,4 ,221 ,10},
{191 ,70 ,186 ,80},
{197 ,70 ,192 ,80},
{231 ,14 ,205 ,66},
{242 ,4 ,207 ,74},
{250 ,0 ,242 ,16},
{219 ,62 ,210 ,80},
{256 ,0 ,251 ,10},
{221 ,70 ,216 ,80},
{262 ,0 ,257 ,10},
{227 ,70 ,222 ,80},
{268 ,0 ,263 ,10},
{233 ,70 ,228 ,80},
{272 ,4 ,269 ,10},
{239 ,70 ,234 ,80},
{245 ,70 ,242 ,76},
{286 ,0 ,246 ,80},
{292 ,0 ,252 ,80},
{276 ,44 ,270 ,56},
{282 ,44 ,276 ,56},
{288 ,44 ,282 ,56},
{316 ,0 ,276 ,80},
{322 ,0 ,282 ,80}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I put this in my pde file :

```
window.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
function handleMouseMove(event) {
event = event || window.event;
mouseX = event.clientX;
mouseY = event.clientY;
}
```

I have to change a bit the way is be drawing on the canvas but at least it moves when I move the mouse outside of the canvas.

Thanks!

UPDATE :

I change also the width & height :

```
width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```